# Need to randomly sample a data set with multiple groups each with multiple factors

Tags: r

**UPDATED QUESTION**
I neglected to include one important aspect in my original question. The code provided by @Jthorpe works great with one column of `STUFF`. However, depending on my data set, I will between 1 to 70 columns to randomly sample at once. In my updated example I have included 3 columns of `STUFF`. So I need to `group_by` `SITE` and `DATE` and then randomly `sample` a single row from multiple columns of `STUFF` at once. Please note how the `RESULT` table retains the order of data across the columns of `STUFF`. For example the first two rows in the `RESULT` table are both 2,4,8 which corresponds to row 2 in the `DATA` table. I hope this is clear. Thanks again.

**Original question**
I need to pseudo-replicate a data set that could have multiple groups. Additionally, each group could have multiple factors. I have written code using for loops to subset the data set, then randomly sample the subset, and then reassemble the resampled data set into a new table. I would like to use some more elegant and flexible code.  I have tried using dplyr (e.g, group_by and sample_n functions), but am having trouble getting the code to properly deal with the variable lengths in factors. I have attached an example data set and the desired result. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
DATA = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                  DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                  STUFF = c(1, 2, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 5000, 6000),
                  STUFF2 = c(2, 4, 60, 80, 200, 400, 600, 10000, 12000),
                  STUFF3 = c(4, 8, 120, 160, 400, 800, 1200, 20000, 24000))



 RESULT = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                    DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                    STUFF = c(2, 2, 30, 30, 200, 300, 300, 6000, 5000),
                    STUFF2 = c(4, 4, 60, 60, 400, 600, 600, 12000, 10000),
                    STUFF3 = c(8, 8, 120, 120, 800, 1200, 1200, 24000, 20000))
```

Comment: You want to sample from `STUFF` while grouped by `SITE` and `DATE`?

Comment: Yes. I want to group by SITE and DATE and randomly sample STUFF. Sorry...I should have been a bit more clear in the text.

Comment: You may want to look at the `sampling` package for a more thoroughly tested solution.

Comment: How do you mean a more thoroughly tested solution? I will be checking to ensure the 'sample' function is properly sampling my groups. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dplyr solution:

```
RESULT <- DATA %>% group_by(SITE,DATE) %>% mutate(STUFF=sample(STUFF,replace= TRUE))
```

Comment: Well....that code is slicker than oily cat poop. The original code I wrote was a series of nested for loops...which was a headache to work with. Thanks!

Comment: What a great analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA)[, sample(STUFF, replace = TRUE), by = .(SITE, DATE)]
```