# Generate random sample using weights by group

Tags: r, random, data.table

I am trying to randomly sample a `data.table` using groups. The sample size of each group will be computed by multiplying the frequency with `Sample_Size`, which is the expected number of rows in the output `data.table`.

I researched this topic on SO. It seems similar threads ([Need to randomly sample a data set with multiple groups each with multiple factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844092/need-to-randomly-sample-a-data-set-with-multiple-groups-each-with-multiple-facto) and [take randomly sample based on groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258690/take-randomly-sample-based-on-groups)) have assumed uniform distribution for weights, which doesn't work for me.

Here's test data:

```
InputDT <- data.table::data.table ("Country"=c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10),rep("C",5),rep("D",2)), "ID"=c(1:20,101:110,201:205,301:302))
```

The objective is to sample IDs by country.

Here's the frequency we want:

```
CountryFreq <- 
 data.table::data.table("Country"=unique(InputDT$Country), "Freq"=c(4/10,2/10,2/10,2/10))
```

Here's the number of rows in the output `data.table`:

```
 Sample_Size <- 10
```

As a rule, let's assume that  `Sample_Size < nrows(InputDT)`

Here's manually created sample output:

```
OutputDT <- structure(list(Country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "D", "D"), ID = c(1, 5, 7, 3, 102, 109, 203, 204, 301, 302
)), .Names = c("Country", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's a test to check whether frequencies are as needed:

```
Hmisc::describe(OutputDT$Country)

OutputDT$Country 
       n  missing distinct 
      10        0        4 

Value        A   B   C   D
Frequency    4   2   2   2
Proportion 0.4 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

Can someone please help me? I've spent almost one day trying to learn sampling in R and then customizing it to my need. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Do we need to use the `CountryFreq` data

Comment: @akrun - Yes, akrun. Absolutely. That has the frequencies we want for each country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `InputDT` with country frequency first before doing the sampling for each country as follows:

```
InputDT[CountryFreq,
    .SD[sample(.N, min(.N, Freq*Sample_Size))], 
    by=.EACHI,
    on=.(Country)]
```

Notes:

`InputDT[i=CountryFreq, on=.(Country)]` joins CountryFreq with InputDT using Country as the key.

`by=.EACHI` performs this `j=.SD[sample(.N, min(.N, Freq*Sample_Size))]` for each row in `i=CountryFreq`. Note `by=.EACHI` only works for an equi-join for now.

`.SD` is Subset of Data of `InputDT`, i.e. each subset of data from `InputDT` for each `Country` in each row of `i` because of `by=.EACHI`. `.SD` is only really within the scope of `InputDT` and can only be used in `j`. See `?data.table`. To learn more, check out **lexical scoping**. A good reference is Advanced R by Hadley Wickham.

`sample(.N, min(.N, Freq*Sample_Size))` samples `Freq*Sample_Size` indices from the number of rows from `.SD` while `min` ensures that you dont sample more than available samples in that country.

Finally, `.SD[sample(.N, min(.N, Freq*Sample_Size))]` subset sampled rows of `.SD`.

---

edit: show sample runs from R console.

```
> InputDT[CountryFreq,
+     .SD[sample(.N, min(.N, Freq*Sample_Size))], 
+     by=.EACHI,
+     on=.(Country)]
    Country  ID
 1:       A  19
 2:       A   7
 3:       A   5
 4:       A   3
 5:       B 109
 6:       B 110
 7:       C 203
 8:       C 205
 9:       D 302
10:       D 301
> InputDT[CountryFreq,
+     .SD[sample(.N, min(.N, Freq*Sample_Size))], 
+     by=.EACHI,
+     on=.(Country)]
    Country  ID
 1:       A  12
 2:       A  19
 3:       A  17
 4:       A  10
 5:       B 110
 6:       B 105
 7:       C 202
 8:       C 203
 9:       D 302
10:       D 301
> InputDT[CountryFreq,
+     .SD[sample(.N, min(.N, Freq*Sample_Size))], 
+     by=.EACHI,
+     on=.(Country)]
    Country  ID
 1:       A   9
 2:       A   7
 3:       A  19
 4:       A   6
 5:       B 106
 6:       B 108
 7:       C 205
 8:       C 201
 9:       D 302
10:       D 301
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am unable to get desired output. IDs from Country A are randomly selected instead of Country B, C and D. Not sure why. Could you please help? It always helps to learn different ways to do the same thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am getting different values for A, B and C when i rerun the code. D has only 2 samples, so sampling 2 out of 2 will always return the same

Comment: Thanks chinsoon. I am getting values from A for B, C and D. B should have values in 1xx range, C should have 2xx range, D should have 3xx range, but I am getting all values in xx range, which belongs to A. If you run akrun's code below, you will the difference. akrun's code is working flawlessly.

Comment: added some sample runs. i think its because the code was missing `.SD` earlier today

Comment: Thank you so much. Wonderful. Could you please explain your code, if you don't mind? This way, readers can understand what's going on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
InputDT[, rbindlist(Map(function(x, y) x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x)), y)], 
        split(.SD, Country), freq))]
```

#### data

```
freq <- c(4, 2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe this code will work only if `InputDT` is sorted as per `freq`, meaning there has to be 1-1 mapping between `freq` and `Country` split. Correct?

Comment: @watchtower  I assume that the freq is in the same order